# How to pass browser as param with protractor multicapabilities?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, automation, protractor

I need help with this and I'm looking if I find some example but I didn't find anything that works for me.

I want to pass the browser as a param via the command line. 
At my work, we've done this: 
[Config.ts, this is inside the config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvyJV.png)

```
    static chromeConfigs = {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--window-size=1550,768', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
    },
    shardTestFiles: false,
    maxInstances: 1,
};

static firefoxConfigs = {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    marionette: 'true',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: ['--headless', '--window-size=1550,768'],
    },
};

static multiCapabilitiesConfigs = [
    {
        browserName: BrowserUtilities.chromeConfigs.browserName,
        chromeOptions: BrowserUtilities.chromeConfigs.chromeOptions,
    },
    //      {
    //          browserName: BrowserUtilities.firefoxConfigs.browserName,
    //          marionette: BrowserUtilities.firefoxConfigs.marionette,
    //          'moz:firefoxOptions': BrowserUtilities.firefoxConfigs['moz:firefoxOptions'],
    //      },
];
```

But I don't know how to use it with an external file as params.ts and make it work. 
[Params external file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXJCN.png)

```
    params: {
    login: {
        email: 'Test',
        password: 'Test',
    },
    browsers: [
        {
            browserName: 'firefox',
            marionette: 'true',
            'moz:firefoxOptions': {
                args: ['--headless', '--window-size=1550,768'],
            },
        },
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--window-size=1550,768', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
            },
            shardTestFiles: false,
            maxInstances: 1,
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code as opposed to screenshots so it can be copied and changed into a answer?

Comment: @DublinDev yeah sure!

Answer (score 0):

if you use capabilities in protractor config file you should be able to pass browser parameter from command line :

Protractor Config file :

`capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
  },`

Command Line Parameter :

`--capabilities.browserName=chrome` or `--capabilities.browserName=firefox`

Comment: Thanks, if I use multicapabilities is the same behavior?

Comment: see explanation here for capabilities and multicapabilities : https://www.seleniumeasy.com/protractor-angularjs-tutorials/capabilities-and-options